# Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repo'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

```
package com.hb;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
@EnableJpaRepositories
public interface **CurrencyExchangeRepository** extends JpaRepository<CurrencyConversion, Long> {
    //Now we can use JpaRepository’s methods: save(), findOne(), findById(), findAll(), count(), delete(), deleteById()…
    // without implementing these methods.

    @Query("SELECT value FROM currency_conversion t WHERE t.from_country = ?1 and t.to_country = ?2")
    CurrencyConversion getCurrencyValue(String fromCurrency, String toCurrency);
}


package com.hb;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.cloud.context.config.annotation.RefreshScope;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RefreshScope
@RestController
public class **CurrencyExchangeSampleController** {

    @Autowired
    CurrencyExchangeRepository repo;

    
    @GetMapping("/chenna")
    public String msg(){
        return "hello chenna";
    }

    @GetMapping("/currency-exchange-service/fromCurrency/{fromCurrency}/toCurrency/{toCurrency}")
    public ExchangeValue retrieveExchangeValue(@PathVariable String fromCurrency,
                                               @PathVariable String toCurrency) {

        System.out.println("msg : " + msg);
        CurrencyConversion cc = impl.getCurrencyValue(fromCurrency, toCurrency);
        System.out.println("value : " + cc.getValue());


    }
}


package com.hb;
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
@ComponentScan("com.hb")
public class **CurrencyExchangeServiceSampleApplication** {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(
                CurrencyExchangeServiceSampleApplication.class,
                args);
    }
}
```

**this is my code and i am getting below error**

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Field **repo** in com.hb.CurrencyExchangeSampleController required a bean of type 'com.hb.CurrencyExchangeRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
- @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.hb.CurrencyExchangeRepository' in your configuration.

Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:53276', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Please suggest why this error is coming, all classes are in same package.

Comment: Can you try moving `@EnableJpaRepository` to the main class (the one annotated by `@SpringBootApplication`) Also make sure you've added an appropriate starter for JPA

Comment: I tried, but getting same error

Comment: Also, why did you put @ComponentScan and excluded DataSource Auto Configuration?

Comment: Remove those annotations from the repostiory. Spring Boot already enables those JPA repositories and `@Repository` on a Spring Data repository it useless (it only takes up space). The problem is yu disabled the `DatasourceAutoConfiguration`, without a `DataSource` how do you expect JPA to connect to your database? So remove the `@EnableAutoConfiguration` from your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class (the `@ComponentScan` can go away as well) and restart your app, make sure you provide the correct information to connect to your database.

Comment: I will remove everything and i will try thanks for reply @M.Denium and Mark

Comment: @MarkBramnik if i dont put @SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class }) then i am getting below error. 
Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.